# seat reservation system in php

Tags: php, ajax

I try to set up a simple seat reservation system for our small theatre in php.
From a textfile, where I save seatnumbers and status (e.g. 1101,f - which means row 11, seat 1, f = free, r = reserved, p = paid, h = handicap-seat), I load small bitmaps, depending on the status, row by row.
Here is the php code for the last row:

```
<?php 
$counter = 0;
$file = 'seats.txt';
$row = file($file);
//starting with the last row - #11
for($i=173;$i > 157;$i--){ 
    $counter = $counter + 1; 
    $string = $row[$i]; 
    if($counter == 9) { echo "&nbsp &nbsp 11 &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp"; } 
    if(substr($string,5,1) == "f") { 
        echo "<img src='seat_free.bmp' /> &nbsp &nbsp"; } 
    else if(substr($string,5,1) == "p") { 
        echo "<img src='seat_paid.bmp' /> &nbsp &nbsp"; } 
    else if(substr($string,5,1) == "r") { 
        echo "<img src='seat_res.bmp' /> &nbsp &nbsp"; } 
    else {
    echo "<img src='seat_hcp.bmp' /> &nbsp &nbsp"; }
}
?>
```

My question now is:
How can I replace a free seat image with a reserved seat image just by clicking on an image (and of course change the status in the textfile)?
Is that possible with php or do I have to use java/ajax?

Comment: why Java/AJAX? Strange combination... Do you mean using JQuery or JavaScript to handle the image click state?

Comment: Sorry, whatever fits! ;) I used to be pretty good in vb a couple of years ago, but I have no experience in AJAX and JQuery, just a little php and javascript.

Comment: I would firstly discover what it is you need to do exactly and find a language that you can use. I would suggest keeping it simple using JQuery. AJAX is fairly straightforwar but only if your familiar with both JQuery and Php methods.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is back end and can't detect image clicks:

Use a JavaScript onclick action for the image, replace src link for free to reserved, then use ajax to run php to update your file